# How to pass attachment reference as dataweave 2.0 field mapping value in Mule 4 to consume SOAP Service

Tags: soap, dataweave, mule4

How to pass xml attachment reference as dataweave 2.0 field mapping value in Mule 4 to consume SOAP Service.
We need to map xml attachment reference as one of the input parameter to consume SOAP Service with Web Service consumer connector.

Comment: Please can you explain with more detail what you are trying to do. May be some input example and expected output. I can not understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

The usage of attachments in the Web Service Consumer is explained in the documentation at https://docs.mulesoft.com/connectors/web-service/web-service-consumer-consume#attachments

Example:

```
<wsc:consume config-ref="config" operation="addClients">
    <wsc:message>
        <wsc:body>#[payload]</wsc:body>
        <wsc:attachments>
          #[{ file1: vars.xmlFile } ]
        </wsc:attachments>
    </wsc:message>
</wsc:consume>
```