# Mule 4: Call SOAP Service with attachment

Tags: mule, multipartform-data, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

How can I send the multipart request without Mtom enable in Mule 4 by Web Service consumer connector?

This is content of attachment:

```
<ee:set-variable variableName="AddAttachmentReq" ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/java
---
{
    "TestImage.JPG": readUrl("https://savannahw2.sg-host.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/image-24.png", 'application/octet-stream')
}
]]></ee:set-variable>
```

**Case1: Disable MTOM** (I catch the request in SoapUI mockup Service)

- I can't see the attachment file: The base64 of attachment is inline the soap:Body.
- I got the response error message:

  AddDocument : Specified File: TestImage.JPG not found.

[Disable MTOM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsmjD.png)

**Case2: Enable MTOM**

- I can see the attachment file.
- But Mtom enable auto adjust code in the soap body:

  <TestImage.JPG>
  <xop:Include href="cid:TestImage.JPG" xmlns:xop="http://....
  </TestImage.JPG>
- I got the response error message:

  org.apache.axis2.databinding.ADBException: Unexpected subelement {http://....com/AddDocServiceImp/}TestImage.JPG

[Mtom Enable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7d34f.png)

I need send the request like this:
[SOAPUI Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sliqg.png)

The WSDL had no element for contain the content of attachment like: content, binaryAttachment, attachments,...

**UPDATE**
I had resolve this issue by using HTTP Request component to mimic WSC consume operation.
Link: [Workaround for various issues with Mule 4 Web Service Consumer Connector](https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/Workaround-for-various-issues-with-Mule-4-W?fbclid=IwAR20lFknJnVuzFRqJTBuvcizaFPlAnY-cbyfgtdeuxgrdWD8WBOiG7GxtlY)

Comment: Have you seen this previous answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/62134431/721855

Comment: Yes, I do the same thing in Case1: Disable MTOM.
The base64 of attachment is append inline the soap:Body.
The Content-Type is only "text/xml; charset=UTF-8"